# Unable to see nodes in neoclipse when connecting to neo4j 2.0.1 server

Tags: neo4j, neoclipse

I downloaded neoclipse for my mac and tried to visualize a neo4j database, but I could see only the relationship types and no properties. No nodes are visible in my neoclipse database graph. Is there anything I should do?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try first:

- In the toolbar above the center panel (where the graph is visualized), click on the "+" button, which increases the traversal depth.
- Towards the right side of the same toolbar, click the downward-pointing-triangle to bring up a menu of what you want to display.

Also, the Help panel should be on right side, and it should contain the Neoclipse User Guide. You should refer to that to get more familiar with Neoclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same bug for Neoclipse 1.8 and Neo4j 2.0.1 CE, but it was gone after upgrade to [Neoclipse 1.9.5](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neoclipse#neoclipse-195).